# How to implement time based tests?

Tags: ios, testing

I have an app that communicates with a server and receives XML data. The app moves between internal states based upon some dates in the XML.

I would like to write some test code for the app but are there any mechanisms for setting the system time when setting things up for the test, and then to alter the system time while the tests are running?

I know the APIs for setting the system time are private, but that is for apps, this is not for an app its test code therefore is there some existing mechanism within SenTestCaseCase for doing something like this?

Comment: Could you refactor your code to not be dependent on the *system* time but instead take a datetime value as a function parameter or property on a class? Sometimes that's an easy solution.

Comment: I would be able to do some unit testing for such code but I need to do some holistic system tests. I can alter the XML such that the times within them are a few seconds apart so the test code can transition states within a short time span, but to be deterministic I still need to be able to repeatedly set the time before the tests run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult at best.

Of course, ideal would be some sort of Mac hack that would reflect a different time base into the iOS simulator, but I've never heard of anything like that.

Failing that, you'd have to "hook" your app.  First (easy part) find *all* uses of `[NSDate date]` and the related "since now" uses and replace with references to MyNSDate.  This version of NSDate would hook the "timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate" class method and "feed" it bogus time values.

The hard part is to somehow booger up all the timers that your app is sensitive to.  I have no idea how you'd go about that.